# Sending Apple device token to server and avoid spoofing

Tags: ios, security, apple-push-notifications

I'm not sure if I'm being over cautions; I'm implementing the ios push notifications and there's is a part where I need to send the device token to the server, so that's clear, all I had to do is send a request like this:

www.mysite.com?registerIosToken=asdfgadsfhgakjhsf

So my server can register the token in the db.

But what if someone sends multiple random requests to this url?, how can I detect ignore fake requests?,

I was thinking using the app public certificate, and I can decrypt it in the server with my private key, but if the key is public, everyone can encrypt it...

Comment: I can't see how anything bad could happen as a consequence, other than if they add millions of them and that causes your server to explode. If they add a token which is not valid then nothing will happen - you'll try and send a push to that token but it won't get delivered. If they send a token which by random happens to be valid, well in order for it to be valid somebody must have your app installed, so your server would already have a copy of that token anyway, and you should not be storing tokens without checking for duplicates anyway.

Comment: But if you really wanted to, you could generate your own private certificates and embed them into your app and sign the https with your private certificate.